# Remove Duplicate Entries From A .txt File - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have the following `eeee.txt` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
            <key>aa</key>
            <string>2012-06-29 17:12:45</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
            <key>bb</key>
            <string>2012-06-29 17:12:59</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
            <key>bb</key>
            <string>2012-06-29 17:13:03</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
            <key>bb</key>
            <string>2012-06-29 17:13:06</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Here, I want to remove the duplicate entries of `bb` and replace them with the latest `bb` entry i.e. the last one (since it is the one with the latest `timestamp` of `2012-06-29 17:13:06`). I want to write it again to my `eeee.txt` file. How can I do that ?? Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load this file into an NSDictionary using "dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:", then create a new NSMutableDictionary and load each entry into it while checking for duplicates. If you need this written back as a text file, use NSDictionary's "writeToFile:atomically:" method.

Comment: Of course - NSDate's "isEqualToDate" method, which means you will have to translate the date from an NSString to an NSDate using NSDateFormatter.